C++ decltype with arguments (class with constructor)
Let's say I have a class T with a constructor T(int b) and child Tchild with a similar constructor Tchild(int b).
How can I use decltype with the argument?
For example:
Let's pretend I don't know those next 2 types:
T abc{};
Tchild def{};

std::vector<*T> vec;
vec.push_back(new decltype(Tchild));  

How can I make new decltype with this constructor -> Tchild(int b) ?
I'm a newbie and my question may be very dumb. I tried to find an answer but I couldn't, maybe I'm asking a bad question.

new decltype(Tchild) -> new Tchild(integer_value_or_variable)

You cannot use decltype to get the dynamic child class of a given T*

You say T and Tchild have constructors that take int parameters. So you need to pass in int values for them, eg:
T abc{1};
Tchild def{2};

T abc{}; and Tchild def{}; will not compile unless those classes also define default constructors, which you did not describe.
In any case, new decltype(Tchild) makes no sense as Tchild is already a type, so you could have just written new Tchild. You probably meant new decltype(def) instead.
But, you still have to provide a int value if you want the Tchild(int b) constructor to be called, eg:
vec.push_back(new decltype(def){3});  

